# Starting (Cranking) problem

Tags: starting, peugeot, peugeot-406

Recently, I have had some problems with my starter. When I turn the ignition on, I hear a clicking sound, then nothing happens (No cranking) for about 3 seconds and then finally it cranks the engine and it fires up normally.
I checked the battery and it was fine.
I removed the starter and took it to an expert shop. They examined the whole starter, disassembled and reassembled everything, changed any part they thought is necessary and put all back together after some lubrication.
I brought the starter back home and re-installed it on the car. However, when I tried to start the car, that annoying click and 3 second delay is still there but after that it cranks the engine over normally.
What do you think causing the problem? Wiring?

Peugeot 406 1.8 16V 2001

I edited this topic to avoid opening a new one.

**Latest update:**

Today, I performed some tests to help identify the problem.
Before explaining the tests, I have to say I discovered something new about the problem.
I found that when I try to start the car early in the morning, it refuses to crank and by turning the ignition key the only thing that happens is that you just hear a clicking noise! I have to keep trying to finally start it up (after about 10 - 11 attempts).
On the contrary, when I drive the car for a while and turn it off, it is much easier to start the car and it almost fires up like a normal car without a problem.

The following are the **voltage drop tests** I did today after 30 mins of driving with a fully charged battery:

**1 -** I connected one lead of my voltmeter to starter + terminal and the other lead to the battery positive terminal. I cranked the engine (engine off - just cranking) and I read 0.1V in voltmeter display.

**2 -** I connected one lead of my voltmeter to starter housing (body) and the other lead to the battery negative terminal, cranked the engine and the result was about 0.1V again.

**3 -** I connected one lead of my voltmeter to starter positive terminal and the other lead to starter housing (to measure how much voltage is received by the starter). Cranked the engine and the result was 11.1 11.2V

**4 -** I connected one lead of my voltmeter to starter st terminal (ignition switch terminal) and the other lead to my battery negative post. Cranked the engine and the result was 10.2V

How do you interpret the above findings?

Comment: What is the year/make/model/engine of the vehicle in question? You said the "I checked the battery and it was fine." How did you check it? How is it "fine"?

Comment: I checked the voltage and it was full of charge. They also said my battery is fine (they tested it).

Comment: Please define "full of charge".

Comment: By " full of charge or fully charged " I mean the battery had 12.7V before starting the car and it didn't drop below 11V during cranking.

Comment: Presuming battery and starter are fine leaves main power wiring; both battery cables and maybe engine ground cable. Are battery cable terminals clean and free of powdery deposits (dried battery acid from venting)? Engine gorund cable clean and free of corrosion?

Comment: @F Dryer - All cables are extremely clean and shiny without any deposits. I checked all terminals and ground straps with multi-meter and all of them were fine (I read the same voltage across all of them).

Comment: I agree with F Dryer, it sounds like a poor connection somewhere. Every connection is suspect. Often times there are “emergency” battery terminals installed where the wires are clamped down to the terminal, and that connection is overlooked. It needs to be checked with a voltmeter while cranking the vehicle to locate the connection issue. Start at the battery and work your way down the wiring one step at a time until located.

Comment: @X-tech2 - Thanks for your comment. Do you mean tests like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qFJ9LLGSrH4

Comment: Yes, however he did skip one thing. I have seen connection issues between the cable and the post at the starter, so make sure you look at EVERY possibility. They also didn't check for voltage drop between the battery post and the terminal. Good luck!